# How would I make this SQL statement only retrieve if all fk_winnerid are null?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Here is my statement:

```
select TournamentID, TournamentDateTime, TournamentName, TournamentTypeName, BossTournamentID 
from vwTournaments 
where tournamentid in 
(
    select distinct(fk_tournamentid) 
    from tournamentprizes 
    where place between 1 
    and (select max(numranks) from tournaments) 
    and fk_winnerid is not null
) 
and TournamentDateTime > '8/29/2013' 
and 
(
    TournamentID like '%%' 
    or TournamentDateTime like '%%' 
    or BossTournamentID like '%%' 
    or TournamentTypeName like '%%' 
    or TournamentName like '%%'
) 
order by TournamentDateTime DESC
```

the part that needs to be fixed is "and fk_winnerid is not null)" I want it to say if all tournamentprizes have a fk_winnerid that is not null. Not just one prize.

Comment: Why all these `like '%%'` ...?

Comment: you have already applied the condition(and fk_winnerid is not null). Wjat exactly you are looking for?

Comment: What's the point of your where `'Like '%%'`? Those are essentially looking for anything so...

Comment: And is the query needed for MySQL or SQL-Server? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a correlated `EXISTS` subquery:

```
from vwTournaments AS t
where NOT EXISTS 
(
    select 1 
    from tournamentprizes 
    where fk_tournamentid = t.tournamentid 
    and place between 1 
                  and (select max(numranks) from tournaments) 
    and fk_winnerid IS NULL
) 
and TournamentDateTime > '20130829' 
and ...
```